# OpenLayers/Angular/ol-cesium : Point vectors show on both 2D/3D map / polygons don't

Tags: openlayers, cesium, angular, ol-cesium

I am working on a existing app made with **Angular 13.**
I use **OpenLayers 6+** and the **npm package ol-cesium**.

I have an Angular component where I display a map (2D - OpenLayers). Everything goes as planned.
I display vector layers on this map such as GeoJSON, point, polygon etc... All good.

I installed the ol-cesium npm package (npm install + linking all the correct scripts/styles etc... on my angular.json file). I can toggle my 3D view without problems.

Here is the issue I experience :

- If I had a point on the map (styled or not), it shows in both 2d OpenLayers map and 3D cesium globe.
- **However, if I want to display a Polygon it just doesn't show up. No console errors or warning. I have been debugging for hours, looking each and every repo from ol-cesium to see what could be different and I don't see anything.**

Have you been aware of such an issue? Because it seems Google is not.

You can check some of my code here (as you can imagine sharing all code from an Angular app is not really going to help).

```
const basicView = new View({
    center: olProj.fromLonLat([10, 49]),
    zoom: 3.2,
    maxZoom: 15,
    minZoom: 1,
});

//MAP-------------------------------------------------------------.
//Map Layer
const map = new Map({
    target: 'map',
    view: basicView,
    controls: defaultControls().extend([
        new FullScreen(),
        new ScaleLine({
            units: 'metric',
        }),
        new ZoomSlider(),
        new OverviewMap({
            className: 'ol-overviewmap ol-custom-overviewmap',
            layers: [new TileLayer({
                source: new XYZ({
                    url: 'https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}'
                }),
                visible: true,
                title: 'esriWorldImagery'
            })],
            collapseLabel: '\u2228',
            label: '\u2227',
            collapsed: true,
        })
    ])
});
map.addLayer(baseLayerGroup)
```

BaseLayerGroup is just a groupe of layer from different tile providers, nothing fancy, just the same as the overviewmap.

Then I can make my points like this :

```
        source: new VectorSource({
            features: [
                new Feature({
                    geometry: new Point([0, 0]),
                })
            ]
        })
```

I make Polygon like this :

```
const polygon = new VectorLayer({
        source: new VectorSource({
            features: [
                new Feature({
                    geometry: new Polygon([array of coordinates]),
                })
            ]
        }),
        style: new Style({
            stroke: strokeStyle,
        })
    })
```

My ol-cesium map :

```
this.ol3d = new OLCesium({map: map});
```

TLDR :

- OpenLayers 2D map shows all kind of feature such as points, polygons etc...
- Cesium-openlayers 3d globe does not show polygons and does not mention any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some progress regarding this issue and I wanted to let you know.

At first, the map I was displayed with the projection EPSG:3857.
Then I had to change the projection (for reasons unrelated to this post) to EPSG:4326.

==> Then I could render the polygons ! It's very slow (can't tell if its slow by design or because the machine I use is slow... both of them I guess).

TLDR : Adding Polygons to a OpenLayers Cesium Map didn't work with EPSG:3857 projection but it (badly) works with EPSG:4326.